# android TabView Activity

Tags: android-tabhost

i have three tab activity in my application(Home,Search,Back),
Now on first tab I have some more activities. Now I want to go previous activity from the current activity so how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just simple call your activity finish and it will take you the previous activity. Like if your activity name is SpalshActivity then do something like
SpalshActivity.this.finish(); it will take you the previous activity but make sure you did not finish the previous activity when you come here from that activity.

Put this provided code line in your back button onClickListenere.

Hope it can help.